# AnalysisException: Syntax error in SQL After multiple join

Tags: sql, hive, syntax-error

I have this query:

```
select * from (    
        select
        minnn.id_demande_diffusion AS ID_DIFFUSION,
        minnn.id_notification as ID_NOTIFICATION,
        minnn.cod_entrep as ID_ENTITE,
        minnn.cod_entrep_assu as ID_ENTITE_GARANTE,
        minnn.CD_ETAT as CD_ETAT,
        to_timestamp(substr(minnn.DT_MAJ, 1, 19), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS DT_ETAT,
        minnn.CD_ANOMALIE,
        minnn.cd_canal as CD_CANAL,
        to_timestamp(minnn.dtmin, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as DT_DEBUT,
        case when minnn.id_demande_diffusion_originale is null then 1 else 0 end as TOP_PREMIERE_DIFFUSION,
        to_timestamp(nvl(lead(minnn.dt_capt)  over (partition by minnn.id_demande_diffusion order by minnn.dt_capt), '${t}'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS DT_FIN,
        "DIFFUSIONS" AS TYPE_ACTE,
        minnn.typ_mvt as TYP_MVT

        from 
        (SELECT *,
        LAG(cd_etat) OVER (PARTITION BY id_notification ORDER BY dt_capt) as prev_cd_etat
        FROM lkr_send_notification as minnn 
        ) as A
join

(

        /////

    ) as B

on minnn.ID_NOTIFICATION=B.ID_NOTIFICATION

left join

(
 //////
        ) as C

on A.ID_DIFFUSION=C.ID_COMMUNICATION;
```

Can someone tell me why is it returning an error syntax? It seems like `A.ID_DIFFUSION` on the last line is not known for the compiler. Only column possible when I write A. is `prev_cd_etat`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out by myself. I had to close parenthesis before as `minnn.`

...

```
from 
        (SELECT *,
        LAG(cd_etat) OVER (PARTITION BY id_notification ORDER BY dt_capt) as prev_cd_etat
        FROM lkr_send_notification) as minnn 
        ) as A
...
```